# How to redirect to a different page depending on the input

Tags: php, html

How can I redirect to a different page depending on what is selected on the form. For example if Cornerback and Interceptions is submitted than it should go to thirdpage.php.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Nfl records</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    Choose a postion:
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="cb">CornerBack</option>
      <option value="S">Saftey</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    Choose a stat:
    <select name="stats">
      <option value="int">Interceptions</option>
      <option value="t">Tackles</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
          $selected_val = $_POST['cars'];
          $selected_val2 = $_POST['stats'];
          if($selected_val == "cb" && $selected_val2 == "int") {
              header("Location: thirdpage.php"); 
          }
      }
    ?>
  </form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your closing `</form>` tag is outside of the closing `</body>` tag.
2. You need to add the `header()` call before any output has occurred on the page (HTML) and add `exit()` right after the `header()` call so the page redirects immediately before any other code on the page gets executed.
3. Your `</br>` tag had a `/` in the wrong place and should have instead been `<br/>`
4. Add `name="submit"` to your submit button if you want to check if `$_POST['submit']` exists after submitting your form.

Rearrange your code like this:

```html
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $selected_val = $_POST['cars'];
        $selected_val2 = $_POST['stats'];
        if($selected_val == "cb" && $selected_val2 == "int") {
            header("Location: thirdpage.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Nfl records</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    Choose a postion:
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="cb">CornerBack</option>
      <option value="S">Saftey</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    Choose a stat:
    <select name="stats">
      <option value="int">Interceptions</option>
      <option value="t">Tackles</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it still does not redirect me. stays on the same page

Comment: Try again, I had a missing `)` in the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`.